# Why does emacs fail to install 'gnu-elpa-keyring-update-' and some other packages?

Tags: emacs

I am trying to install a fresh version of Emacs.
I am starting with a `.emacs.d` which contains only my initialization file `init.el`.

I am using Emacs 26.2 on MacOS with `package.el`.

This is how my packages are initialised:

```
(append-to-list package-archives
                '(("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
                  ("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
                  ("org-elpa" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")))

(package-initialize)
```

When I start Emacs, it downloads many packages correctly but I receive the following errors for some of them:

```
Error (use-package): Failed to install gnu-elpa-keyring-update: Package ‘gnu-elpa-keyring-update-’ is unavailable
Error (use-package): Cannot load gnu-elpa-keyring-update
Error (use-package): Failed to install deadgrep: Package ‘spinner-1.7.3’ is unavailable
Error (use-package): Failed to install undo-tree: Package ‘undo-tree-’ is unavailable
Error (use-package): Failed to install clj-refactor: Package ‘queue-0.2’ is unavailable
Error (use-package): Failed to install cider: Package ‘queue-0.2’ is unavailable
```

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the solution is:

`(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")`

https://github.com/org2blog/org2blog/blob/wip/docs/DebuggingStories.org

Comment: See also [Bug#36725 - Emacs can't connect to gnu elpa](https://debbugs.gnu.org/36725), should be fixed in 26.3.